# Disable the minute selection for MatMomentDatetimeModule in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, datetimepicker

I am using MatMomentDateModule and MatMomentDatetimeModule for the datetime input in my angular application.

I would like to disable the minute selection but I did not found any solutions for that.

Here is my html snippet with the datetime selection:

```
<mat-form-field fxFlex>
      <mat-placeholder>Start Date</mat-placeholder>
      <mat-datetimepicker-toggle [for]="datetimeStartPicker" matSuffix></mat-datetimepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datetimepicker #datetimeStartPicker type="datetime" [timeInterval]="5">
      </mat-datetimepicker>
      <input matInput formControlName="SelectedStartUtcISO" [matDatetimepicker]="datetimeStartPicker" required
        autocomplete="false">
    </mat-form-field>
```

I have also tried to set the timeInterval to 0 and to 60 but it does not realy help

Comment: This is a feature which needs to be implemented by the DateTime picker. There is an open feature request for this feature: https://github.com/kuhnroyal/mat-datetimepicker/issues/144